# Cast NSDictionary to as Mutable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an iPhone application that makes use of an API. Among the API calls, there's one that returns a JSON Dictionary with 3 arrays, each of them containing a set of dictionaries.

Here's how i'm using it:

```
NSMutableDictionary * allthethings [self FetchAllTheThings]; // Returns the big dictionary

NSMutableArray * oneofthethings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [allthethings valueForKey:@"First"]];
```

etc etc.

Then when I'm looping through the "oneofthethings" array and setting a new value on one of the dicts i get a SIGABRT, presumably because the dictionaries contained within are not mutable.

So my question is this: Is there any way to sort of tell the array to store them as mutables? Or will i have to loop through it and copy each of the dictionaries to a mutable analog?

Comment: Don’t presume. If the problem is that you’re trying to mutate a non-mutable collection, your log will say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going to have to create a mutable copy.  Nsdictionary has a mutableCopy method to make it easy, but you can imagine this would be inefficient if called a lot

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will have to loop through the mutable collection and make all of its members mutable. I would advise you to you modify your `FetchAllTheThings` method to return a collection with members that are already mutable.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create mutable copies.  The enclosing array can't turn an object of one type into an object of another type; it's just a container.  It doesn't store them "as" anything, mutable or non-mutable.  It just holds onto pointers to them.  The type of an object is determined by the way you instantiate it, not what it is contained by.

Answer (score 0):

### NSMutableDictionary from NSDictionary

---

**Example:** Use the `mutableCopy` method on your NSDictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *YOUR_MUTABLE_COPY = [YOUR_ORIG_DICT mutableCopy];
```

---

**Example:** Add/Edit a *key & object* in it

```
[YOUR_MUTABLE_COPY setObject:someObject forKey:@"someKey"];
```